# Why is the CakePHP authentication component not hashing my password?

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I'm using [CakePHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CakePHP) 1.2 with Auth and ACL components.

In my user register action, the password is coming in unhashed.  Specifically, this expression:

```
if ($this->data['User']['password'] !=
    $this->Auth->password($this->data['User']['confirm_password']))
```

This is evaluating to true, even when I submit identical values for `password` and `confirm_password`.  I know that password is unhashed because when I remove the call to `Auth->password`, the expression evaluates to false.

I expected the Auth module to automagically hash the password.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is my view:

```
<?php
    echo $form->create('User', array('action' => 'register'));

    echo $form->input('email',
                      array('after' => $form->error(
                        'email_unique', 'This email is already registered.')));
    echo $form->input('password');
    echo $form->input('confirm_password', array('type' => 'password'));
    echo $form->end('Register');
?>
```

Here is my register action from the user controller:

```
function register(){
    if ($this->data) {
        if ($this->data['User']['password'] !=
            $this->Auth->password($this->data['User']['confirm_password'])) {

            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Password and Confirm Password must match.', true));
            $this->data['User']['password'] = '';
            $this->data['User']['confirm_password'] = '';
        }
        else{
            $this->User->create();
            if ($this->User->save($this->data)){
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'), null, true);
            }
            else {
                $this->data['User']['password'] = '';
                $this->data['User']['confirm_password'] = '';
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Some problem saving your information.', true));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my `appController` where I include the `Auth` and `Acl` modules:

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    var $components = array('Acl', 'Auth');

    function beforeFilter(){
        if (isset($this->Auth)) {
            $this->Auth->allow('display');
            $this->Auth->fields =
              array(
                'username' => 'email',
                'password' => 'password');
            $this->Auth->authorize = 'actions';
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CakePHP won't hash passwords unless username contains a submitted value.  I'm replacing the username field with email.  However, I remapped those fields by setting the Auth->fields array.  However, I was doing that in the appController instead of userController.  So moving this line:

```
$this->Auth->fields = array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password');
```

out of appController into userController solved it.
Now the question becomes "Why can't I reset the Auth->fields in appController?"

Answer (score 2):

You're probably overriding `AppController::beforeFilter()` with your `UsersController::beforeFilter()`.

To "fix" it, just put `parent::beforeFilter()` at the beginning of the function.

Answer (score 1):

You should hash password before saving to database. Place this function into your User model:

```
function beforeSave() {
  if(isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password']))
    $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = Security::hash($this->data[$this->alias]['password'], null, true);
  return true;
}
```

And don't forget to put this in `beforeFilter()` to your users controller:

```
if(in_array($this->action, array('register'))) {
  $this->Auth->fields = array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'wrongfield');
}
```

That means that password will NOT be hashed during registration process (in case of failed validation of register form).

Comment: This sounds awesome, but I'm confused on one thing - if we specify it to not hash the password when registering - how will their password work?  Or.. when will we hash it?

Answer (score 0):

i think you are looking for

```
hashPasswords ($data)
```

look at these pages.  They should point you in the right direction. You can also try changing your debugging level in the core config file.  changing it from 0 (production) to 3 allows you to see you sql output.  may be helpful.

[AuthComponent-Methods](http://book.cakephp.org/view/247/AuthComponent-Methods)

[Cakephp  troubleshooting](http://book.cakephp.org/view/565/Troubleshooting-Auth-Problems)

Sorry i can't do anything but point you in the right direction.  I'm new to cakephp.