# Why isn't my password hashing?

Tags: cakephp

So, I looked around and checked SO as well. My question similar to this: [Why is the CakePHP authentication component not hashing my password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617471/why-is-the-cakephp-authentication-component-not-hashing-my-password) except that I cannot get it to work.

My password is unhashed upon registration.

In my Users Controller:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('register', 'logout'); 
    $this->Auth->fields = array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password');
}
```

View:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
    <fieldset>

        <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('email');
        echo $this->Form->input('password');
        ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit'));?>
```

And I have some validators for the `email` field. The problem is, the password is being stored as plaintext. I thought 
the `Auth->fields` line should have taken care of this, but it isn't. I know CakePHP only hashes if `username` and `password` in the `$data` are both populated, but I clearly remapped it, so it should have hashed correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using CakePHP 2.x, Auth won't hash your password automatically anymore

From the docs at http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html

> AuthComponent no longer automatically hashes every password it can
>   find. This was removed because it made a number of common tasks like
>   validation difficult. You should never store plain text passwords, and
>   before saving a user record you should always hash the password. You
>   can use the static AuthComponent::password() to hash passwords before
>   saving them. This will use the configured hashing strategy for your
>   application.

Comment: Oh GOSH. NO WONDER! Does this mean Auth->fields is useless now?

Comment: It's still in use by Auth component to validate password when your user logs in, you just need to hash it manually :)

Comment: I recommend using a behavior to keep the code DRY: http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/